# load plain html file with javascript quickly with little server load

Tags: javascript, html, performance, xmlhttprequest

### Situation:

On my Blog I have an overview page with a set of filters which the user can use to search for specific blog entries. The articles are then displayed in a small preview form:
[image]

I already have the implementation which returns the weblinks of the searched pages here for a better understanding of what im doing:
https://julianbechtold.de/de/informatics/overview.html

### Goal:

I would like to download the plain html code of the blog articles (no images, scripts or anything, just the text/html) in order to grab some information of the pages such as title, first paragraph)

### Question:

Say, I have a blog entry in the path articles/pokerbot-part-1.html
How do I load the page with javascript the best way?

I currently have code in order to obtain an index list with all blog entries:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        UpdatePage(this.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "articles.csv", true);
xhttp.send();
```

would this work for html files as well?
Does this put stress such as loading images on the server or does is just fetch the html file, which is then contained in responseText?

### Alternative Idea:

I currently have my blog in multiple Languages so I have a self-made content management bot.
This content management bot currently creates the static recent articles as well as a tiny preview image which I can use handily.
It would be possible to prefetch that information and put it into a plain text file for each article which could be loaded. This way, I also do not have to load the  bloat. Would that be recommended?

Comment: What if you *visit* (in advance) the page referenced by the link with, say, puppeteer and return a thumbnail of a screenshot?

Comment: puppeteer appears to be a chromium interface. I already know selenium for such tasks but its not my goal. The webpage in the end looks different of what I want to present to my viewers as a preview. Additionally this would circumvent accessibility for the page such as for blind viewers. Google usually gives hefty penalties for such things

Comment: mainly due to text to image conversion. Which would aso make the page less machinereadable